# Clean Kafka topic in a cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I know I can clean Kafka topic on a broker by either deleting logs under /data/kafka-logs/topic/* or by setting retention.ms config to 1000. I want to know how can clean topics in a multi-node cluster. Should I stop Kafka process on each broker, delete logs and start Kafka or only leader broker would suffice? If I want to clean by setting retension.ms to 1000, do I need to set it on each broker?

Comment: When you set the topic retention (to any value, not just 1000), it's applied to each replica already. Don't restart anything unless you want the cluster to experience downtime

Answer (score 0):

To delete all messages in a specific topic, you can run `kafka-delete-records.sh`

For example, I have a topic called **`test`**, which has **4** `partitions`.

Create a `Json` file , for example `j.json`:

```
{

"partitions": [

    {

        "topic": "test",

        "partition": 0,

        "offset": -1

    }, {

        "topic": "test",

        "partition": 1,

        "offset": -1

    }, {

        "topic": "test",

        "partition": 2,

        "offset": -1

    }, {

        "topic": "test",

        "partition": 3,

        "offset": -1

    }

],

"version": 1

}
```

now delete all messages by this command :

```
/opt/kafka/confluent-4.1.1/bin/kafdelete-records --bootstrap-server 192.168.XX.XX:9092 --offset-json-file j.json
```

After executing the command, this message will be displayed

```
Records delete operation completed:
partition: test-0   low_watermark: 7
partition: test-1   low_watermark: 7
partition: test-2   low_watermark: 7
partition: test-3   low_watermark: 7
```

if you want to delete one topic, you can use `kafka-topics` :

for example, I want to delete `test` topic :

```
 /opt/kafka/confluent-4.0.0/bin/kafka-topics --zookeeper 109.XXX.XX.XX:2181  --delete --topic test
```

**You do not need to restart Kafka**